# Angular -fill one column based on server response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, angular-file-upload

I'm new to angular so sorry if this is a very basic question.

I built a client-server app, that allows to upload files, then validates them (some internal rules) and returns log file in case the validation failed.

I'm using [Angular File Upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) module for the client side, the [simple](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/tree/master/examples/simple) example.

The response from server looks like this (JSON)

```
{"status":"FAILED","entity":"download/logs/24f307d3-8964-4a5b-8d66-0763503892b1/","errors":[]}
```

What I want to do is to upload the download link (from response.entity) for every file.

What I get is same link for all files (the one from the last file)

When I check what is happening in debug mode (F12) I do see that the parameters are changing but somehow they are being overridden with the last one.

I think that I have to use ng-repeat somehow, but the thing is that it is already being used for other columns.

Please help.

MY html table:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="50%">Name</th>
      <th ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">Size</th>
      <th ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">Progress</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th align="justify">Actions</th>
      <th>Valid</th>
      <th>Log</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
      <td>{{ item.file.name }}</td>
      <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item.file.size/1024/1024|number:2 }} MB</td>
      <td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
        <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': item.progress + '%' }"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <span ng-show="item.isSuccess"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
        <span ng-show="item.isCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i></span>
        <span ng-show="item.isError"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
      </td>
      <td nowrap>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-click="item.upload()" ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="item.cancel()" ng-disabled="!item.isUploading">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="item.remove()">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
        </button>
      </td>
      <td ng-show="item.isSuccess">
        {{this.uploader.validationStatus }}
      </td>
      <td ng-show="uploader.showLog">
        <a href={{this.uploader.logURL}} target="_blank">Log</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

I'm talking about 2 last columns:

```
  <td ng-show="item.isSuccess">
    {{this.uploader.validationStatus }}
  </td>
  <td ng-show="uploader.showLog">
    <a href={{this.uploader.logURL}} target="_blank">Log</a>
  </td>
```

I did the following change in the controller.js file:

```js
uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
    console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    var resp = JSON.stringify(response.entity);

    if (resp == "\"Success\"") {
      this.validationStatus = "Yes";
      this.showLog = false;
    } else {
      this.validationStatus = "No";
      this.logURL = resp.replace(/\"/g, "");
      this.showLog = true;
    }
```

**The solution:**

changes in controllers.js file:

```js
uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
  console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
  if (response.status === 'FAILED') {
    fileItem.validationStatus = "No";
    fileItem.logUrl = response.entity;
    fileItem.showLog = true;

  } else {
    fileItem.validationStatus = "Yes";
    fileItem.showLog = false;
  }
};
```

Changes in html file:

```html
<td ng-show="item.isSuccess" ng-class="{green: item.validationStatus == 'Yes', red: item.validationStatus == 'No'}">
  {{item.validationStatus}}
</td>
<td ng-show="item.showLog">
  <a href={{item.logUrl}} target="_blank">Log</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

following line

```
this.logURL = resp.replace(/\"/g, "");
```

overrides the logUrl value with every new file upload completion and saves it on uploader object. That is why you see only the last value for each item in the uploader.queue

Try to save each URL separately in dictionary object, use the filename as a key and then reference the url information accordingly during the *ng-repeat* iteration

for example it can be something like this :

```
uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {

    console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    var resp = JSON.stringify(response.entity);
    this.logUrlList = {};
    if(resp=="\"Success\""){
        this.validationStatus = "Yes";
        this.showLog = false;
    }else{
        this.validationStatus = "No";
        this.logUrlList[fileItem.file.name] = resp.replace(/\"/g, "");
        this.showLog = true;

    }
 }
```

the html will be like this:

```
 <td ng-show="uploader.showLog">
     <a href={{this.uploader.logUrlList[item.file.name]}} target="_blank">Log</a>
 </td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer. Could you help me with an example? Where do I put this dicotionary object? Do I need a separate controlle for it?

Comment: If you have a way to upload your code to fiddler of some kind, I'll be glad to have a look again

Answer (score 0):

I got this working!

My json response from the server:

```
{"filename":"Hypnotoad.mp4","link":"/hypnotoad.mp4","size":1858796}
```

That's my controller:

```
uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
    console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    fileItem.file.link = JSON.stringify(response.link).replace(/\"/g, "");
    fileItem.file.linkname = JSON.stringify(response.filename).replace(/\"/g, "");
};
```

And my html:

```
<td ng-show="uploader.isHTML5">
    <a href={{item.file.link}} target="_blank">{{item.file.linkname}}</a>
</td>
```

Example above also works, but only for last element from queue. My example works for all elements in queue.